# How do variables work if I want em for all structs available?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

Lets say I have two structs in a swiftui file. How do I declare a bool variable (that is false by default) and let it get access to all structs like a public variable. I need this because in my case is a button changing the value of this variable in another struct, but it can't because it doesn't work with @state or @binding. I get this error when using @Binding var varName = false "No exact matches in call to initializer". I just need a variable that can be changed its value from other structs. I already tried it with a class and an observable object but this didn't work either.

Comment: Did you have a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67949372/ios-how-to-switch-views-from-login-to-main-content-swiftui

Comment: dude, why are you yelling at the title

Comment: why you don't use if-else?

Comment: What's wrong with that? I mean you could use something custom, but this is not the right way. It can problematic in terms of performance and usability.

Comment: `TabView`, `if else`, `switch`.... Any solution you create with any number of tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an state in your content view. There you can observe that state variable to see if the user is logged in or not.
If is logged in, you navigate to the main screen. If not, you just go to the login screen. That way you define the navigation the app should take.

Be aware that you need to pass that state variable to the login screen in order to be able to change its value, so the content view can react to that change.